# Call onload event from document.ready in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can I call the onload event from the document.ready of jQuery, like the below:

```
$(function() {
onloadfunc(param);
});
```

**VS:**

```
<body onload = "onloadfunc(param);">
```

Are the above two same?

How can I call onloadfunc(param); in JQuery on Load and not on DOM ready?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

nop,
this :

```
$(function() {
});
```

is equivalent to

```
$(document).ready(function(){
});
```

which is triggered before the onload event.

You can call `onload` with jQuery like this :

```
$(window).load(function(){
});
```

--

to answer your question, you can do something like this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).load(function(){
        onloadfunc(param);
    });
});
```

wich is not the best code i've ever written... :D

Answer (score 0):

The $(document).ready() jQuery event fires sooner than onload. The load event waits for all assets to be fully loaded:

> While JavaScript provides the load event for executing code when a
>   page is rendered, this event does not get triggered until all assets
>   such as images have been completely received. In most cases, the
>   script can be run as soon as the DOM hierarchy has been fully
>   constructed. The handler passed to .ready() is guaranteed to be
>   executed after the DOM is ready, so this is usually the best place to
>   attach all other event handlers and run other jQuery code. When using
>   scripts that rely on the value of CSS style properties, it's important
>   to reference external stylesheets or embed style elements before
>   referencing the scripts.